# Import all values to excel

Tags: python, pandas

New to Python and I was wondering how to export some 900 values calculated from python to excel. Below is my code. `t` and `amp` are column headings in the excel file I imported.

```
x1 = b580['t']
y1 = b580['amp']
peaks1, _ = find_peaks(y1, distance = 5)
log580 = y1[peaks1].loc[37:921]
print(log580)
```

I get the results as:

```
41     14.482799
50     14.251082
59     14.019365
69     13.787648
78     14.019365
        ......  
875     3.283384
885     2.915556
894     3.099470
903     2.547729
913     2.915556
```

How do I get all the ... values?

Comment: the simplest way is to write them as csv and open it from Excel. Just add a comma after the first column (or after every column, if that's not really your file) and change the file extension to csv :-)

Comment: Supposing you are using pandas, look at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html or https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If log580 is a dataframe ;

```
log580.to_excel("filename.xlsx")
```

or

```
log580.to_csv("filename.csv")
```

If not, convert it to dataframe.

They both are in pandas package. It is the easiest way I guess. The headers of excel are will be same with dataframe.